# Running npm start after creating a React app with: [npx create-react-app app-name doesn't] doesn't start anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am following the instructions from the official reactJs github repo :
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app
1.

> npm install -g create-react-app

2.

> npx create-react-app app-name

After running :

> npm start

Nothing happens as you may see in the following screenshot of the command line:
[image]

Obviously: http://localhost:3000/ doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea why npm start doesn't do anything?

Comment: By any chance do you hyphen in you app name? Could you please try giving a name to `create-react-app` without dashes if you face with the same result? Exampe: `npx create-react-app appname` Thanks!

Comment: What are your `node` and `npm` versions?

Comment: @norbitrial I have created a new amm with the name 'appname' and still the same result

Comment: @VictorF node: v10.15.3 npm: 6.4.1

Comment: You don't need `npm install -g create-react-app`. See this answer after the 'However,' part https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515134/7692076