# Error while installing create-react-app globally using npm

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am unable to install react js using NPM. I am getting following error.
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 12.3.1 (ia32) and npm.

C:\Users\User>npm install create-react-app -g

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason:

unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-14T05_54_58_7

16Z-debug.log

I am form India and I am not using any corporate firewall or VPN.

Comment: Check this answer, after *However,* https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515134/7692076 I don't know if this will resolve your problem, but try.

Comment: Maybe check to ensure you opened a terminal "as administrator". I've run into node install issues when trying to install packages globally. (Though that usually fails for me with a different error)

Comment: its certificate which is not valid. Try npm config set strict-ssl false

Comment: Please set environment variables and then install npm globally

Comment: @GovindSoni could you please elaborate on this. I am very new to NPM. That's why I have no idea what is environment variable.

Comment: Yeah sure I am posting my answer and hoping it would help you out

Comment: Hey @PiyaliGhosh I have posted my answer please check and let me know if it works

Comment: @GovindSoni... Thanks..I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

hey can you try using `npx create-react-app ${your project name}`

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following command in the command line and worked for me:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

**Although it's not a great idea.**

run this command to turn it on again:

```
npm config set strict-ssl true
```

Answer (score 0):

Download Node.js archive

- Download latest version of Node.js installable archive file from [Node.js Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

After successfully installing NodeJS, we can start installing React upon it using npm. You can install ReactJS in two ways.

```
- Using webpack and babel.
- Using the create-react-app command.
```

But I am telling you about Using the create-react-app command:

```
- Instead of using webpack and babel you can install ReactJS more simply by installing create-react-app.

Browse through the desktop and install the Create React App using command prompt as shown below: 

Step 1: go to your specific directory and run below commands inside the folder like as below:
Step 2: d:\reactproject\>npx create-react-app my-app
Step 3: cd my-app
Step 4: npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your date is right.
If it's not run this and try again:

```
sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
```