# Create-react-app fails to create project (incorrect syntax)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

when I try to use `create-react-app`, it wont work with following details:

```
create-react-app robofriends

Creating a new React app in C:\test\robofriends.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

/F was unexpected at this time.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
/F was unexpected at this time.

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting robofriends/ from C:\test
```

---

Comment: Try using the method suggested after *However,* here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515134/7692076

Comment: not sure the way you are executing the command but if you have successfully installed the create-react-app and executing the command then it should work or at lease it  should not give this error.  if  you are copy pasting the command on command prompt check if no extra characters are getting pasted, best way manually  typing the command and execute it

Comment: using npx cauesd same error. and I dont know what is /F as I run without any parameters or commands